# webix resets treetable state after adding/deleting nodes

Tags: webix

In treetable I have one of the columns - dropdown list. As default its value is "no changes". When I add/remove nodes from tree, for all nodes dropdown list returns to the default value "no changes". How can I prevent it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a native HTML select rendered as a part of tree item, there is no easy way to preserve its state, as tree can repaint the item at any time.

Check http://webix.com/snippet/147906cc , it shows how you can store state of select item in the data object, so it will be correctly preserved during repainting.